# i can't connect to input container. but the container is acccessible and the file is there

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I learning azure, specifically datafactory, so in a basic exercice.

1 - I should create a input container, and a output container (using azure sorage 2).

2 - After that, i created the datasets for input and output.

3 - And finally. I should connect the dataflow to my input dataset.

but

i can test conections on the datasets to prove that i created it without problems. but i cant test the connection on my dataflow to the input dataset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO49h.png)

i tryed

- recreating it with different names.
- keep only the needed file in the storage
- use different input file (i am using a sample similar to the "movies.csv" expected to the exercise.

Comment: Could you please provide your input dataset image?

Answer (score 0):

I created azure blob container and uploaded file

[image]

I created linked service with azure storage account

[image]

I created a dataset with above linked service following below procedure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tested the connection, it connected successfully.

[image]

I didn't get any error. The error which you mentioned above is related to dynamic content. If you assign any parameters in dataset provide the values of parameters correctly. I added parameters in dataset as below

[image]

I try to test the dataset I got error:

[image]

I added values for parameters in debug settings

[image]

Tested the connection, it connected successfully

[image]

Otherwise add the sink to the dataflow and try to debug it, it may work.

Comment: i don t know why, but i discovered that when i create a new dataflow with new datasets, i need to retart de debug, so the connections will work again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

when i am working with "debug on" and for some reason i create another "data flow", you cant connect to the new datasets.

But

if I restart the debug (put off and on again), the connections start working again.